# Calculate row means on subset of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a sample data frame:

```
C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)

DF
    ID C1 C2 C3
  1  A  3  3  5
  2  B  2  7  4
  3  C  4  3  3
  4  D  4  4  6
  5  E  5  5  3
```

What is the best way to create a second data frame that would contain the `ID` column and the mean of each row? Something like this:

```
ID  Mean
A    3.66
B    4.33
C    3.33
D    4.66
E    4.33
```

Something similar to:

```
RM<-rowMeans(DF[,2:4])
```

I'd like to keep the means aligned with their `ID`'s.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Calculate row means on a subset of columns:**

Create a new data.frame which specifies the first column from DF as an column called ID and calculates the mean of all the other fields on that row, and puts that into column entitled 'Means':

```
data.frame(ID=DF[,1], Means=rowMeans(DF[,-1]))
  ID    Means
1  A 3.666667
2  B 4.333333
3  C 3.333333
4  D 4.666667
5  E 4.333333
```

Comment: and Eric Leschinski: if we want to measure standard deviation or some 90th percentile, can use rowSDs like that?

Answer (score 33):

Starting with your data frame `DF`, you could use the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

## EDIT: As suggested by @MichaelChirico, setDT converts a
## data.frame to a data.table by reference and is preferred
## if you don't mind losing the data.frame
setDT(DF)

# EDIT: To get the column name 'Mean':

DF[, .(Mean = rowMeans(.SD)), by = ID]

#      ID     Mean
# [1,]  A 3.666667
# [2,]  B 4.333333
# [3,]  C 3.333333
# [4,]  D 4.666667
# [5,]  E 4.333333
```

Comment: Thanks. Also note from `class(DF)` that you don't _lose_ the `data.frame`, in the sense that any function looking for a `data.frame` object should accept `DF` after `setDT` (especially now that `data.table` is on the mature side)

Comment: What if I want instead the row mean between C2 and C3 only?

Comment: Then you can use `DF[, .(Mean = rowMeans(.SD)), by = ID, .SDcols = c("C2", "C3")]`. The argument `.SDcols` determines which columns you want to include in `.SD`. @user3841581

Comment: @BenBarnes In my case I am not sure about the actual number of columns I want to take rowMeans, they could be 196 in some cases while 198 in other and so on. But one thin which is common is the initial of their name which are like Mgw.1, Mgw.2 ... Mgw.196 similarly Hel.1, Hel.2 ... Hel.198 So what I want to do is donont touch intial 5 columns of the data.table then all those which has initials Mgw, take their rowMeans and assign it to MGW (delete all individual column, just keep one with mean value) and so on for the rest of the columns. Can you guide me how can I do that?

Comment: @Newbie that sounds like a new question, which you should post on its own.

Comment: @BenBarnes Can you kindly help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618110/calculate-rowmeans-on-a-range-of-column-variable-number) question

Comment: @BenBarnes Hi, I am going to find the mean of every 10 columns of my data (which has 1000 columns and some NA data) how should I do it?Can you please guide me?Thanks :)

Comment: @Shalen, I'd recommend asking a new question. It's a bit too involved for a comment and not entirely clear what you expect as output: `rowMeans` or the grand mean. Plus it doesn't look like you have an `ID` column.

Answer (score 25):

You can create a new row with `$` in your data frame corresponding to the Means

```
DF$Mean <- rowMeans(DF[,2:4])
```

Answer (score 14):

Using *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  transmute(ID,
            Mean = rowMeans(across(C1:C3)))
```

Or

```
DF %>%
  transmute(ID,
            Mean = rowMeans(select(., C1:C3)))

#   ID     Mean
# 1  A 3.666667
# 2  B 4.333333
# 3  C 3.333333
# 4  D 4.666667
# 5  E 4.333333
```

Comment: I would update this to use `across` instead of `select`. `across` still allows for tidy select helpers. The output of `across` is a data frame so `rowMeans` will still work on it and you do not need the dot notation.

Answer (score 3):

`rowMeans` is nice, but if you are still trying to wrap your head around the `apply` family of functions, this is a good opprotunity to begin understanding it.

```
DF['Mean'] <- apply(DF[,2:4], 1, mean)
```

Notice I'm doing a slightly different assignment than the first example. This approach makes it easier to incorporate it into for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Awnser adapted from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832675/alternative-faster-approach-to-dynamically-create-row-means-for-multiple-group/72832888#72832888) for N different groups of columns

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
row_means <- DF %>% 
        dplyr::select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
        split.default(stringr::str_remove(names(df), '[0-9]')) %>% 
        map(rowMeans) %>% 
        setNames(paste0("mean_", names(.)))
    DF %>% 
        mutate(
            !!!row_means
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

`rowwise()` in `dplyr` can be used in such situations

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 

DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(ID,
            Mean = mean(c_across(C1:C3))) 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   ID     Mean
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A      3.67
#> 2 B      4.33
#> 3 C      3.33
#> 4 D      4.67
#> 5 E      4.33
```

Still, if you want to use `rowMeans` that can also be used in piped syntax

```r
DF %>% 
  mutate(Mean = rowMeans(.[-1]))

#>   ID C1 C2 C3     Mean
#> 1  A  3  3  5 3.666667
#> 2  B  2  7  4 4.333333
#> 3  C  4  3  3 3.333333
#> 4  D  4  4  6 4.666667
#> 5  E  5  5  3 4.333333
```

`.` is actually a special argument which passes the result of previous piped syntax to next pipe operation.

Answer (score 0):

(Another solution using `pivot_longer` & `pivot_wider` from latest `Tidyr` update)

You should try using pivot_longer to get your data from wide to long form Read latest tidyR update on pivot_longer & pivot_wider (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html)

```
library(tidyverse)
C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)
```

Output here

```
  ID     mean
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A      3.67
2 B      4.33
3 C      3.33
4 D      4.67
5 E      4.33
```