# In R, use dplyr::across and compute difference between 2 columns, for multiple column prefixes

Tags: r, dplyr

```
zed <- data.frame(
  aAgg = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
  bAgg = c(8, 16, 24, 32),
  aPg = c(6, 9, 11, 24),
  bPg = c(7, 15, 22, 26)
)

diff_func <- function(col) {
  return(`{col}Agg` - `{colPg}`)
}

zed %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(.cols = c('a', 'b'), .fns = diff_func, .names = "{col}Diff"))

# we want the output that this outputs, without having to have a mutate for each field.
zed <- zed %>%
  dplyr::mutate(aDiff = aAgg - aPg) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(bDiff = bAgg - bPg)
```

We are attempting to use dplyr's `across` function to create multiple columns. For each column prefix (`a` and `b` in this scenario), we'd like to compute the difference between `prefixAgg` - `prefixPg`, and name the new column `prefixDiff`. The last 3 lines of code in the example above generate the desired output. Our `diff_func` is currently not correct, throwing an error.

Is there a function we can pass to `across` that will generate this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may need to loop over either the 'Agg' columns or 'Pg' columns and `get` the corresponding columns after replacing the substring from column names (`cur_column()`) and modify the `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
zed %>%
   mutate(across(ends_with("Agg"), ~ .x -
   get(str_replace(cur_column(), "Agg", "Pg")), 
   .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'Agg', 'Diff')}"))
```

-output

```
  aAgg bAgg aPg bPg aDiff bDiff
1    5    8   6   7    -1     1
2   10   16   9  15     1     1
3   15   24  11  22     4     2
4   20   32  24  26    -4     6
```

---

Or use two `across`, get the difference - the resulting column will be a data.frame/tibble, then `unpack` the data.frame column

```
library(tidyr)
zed %>% 
  mutate(Diff = across(ends_with("Agg")) - across(ends_with("Pg"))) %>% 
  unpack(where(is.data.frame), names_sep = "")
# A tibble: 4 × 6
   aAgg  bAgg   aPg   bPg DiffaAgg DiffbAgg
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     5     8     6     7       -1        1
2    10    16     9    15        1        1
3    15    24    11    22        4        2
4    20    32    24    26       -4        6
```

NOTE: If needed, can rename the columns

```
zed %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("Agg"), 
  .names = "{str_remove(.col, 'Agg')}Diff") - 
      across(ends_with("Pg")))
  aAgg bAgg aPg bPg aDiff bDiff
1    5    8   6   7    -1     1
2   10   16   9  15     1     1
3   15   24  11  22     4     2
4   20   32  24  26    -4     6
```

---

Or may also use `dplyover` with `across2`

```
library(dplyover)
zed %>%
  mutate(across2(ends_with("Agg"), ends_with("Pg"), `-`, 
  .names_fn = ~ str_replace(.x, "Agg_.*", "Diff")))
  aAgg bAgg aPg bPg aDiff bDiff
1    5    8   6   7    -1     1
2   10   16   9  15     1     1
3   15   24  11  22     4     2
4   20   32  24  26    -4     6
```

Answer (score 3):

`split.default` and `dplyr` solution (probably close to the fastest solution you can get; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832675/alternative-faster-approach-to-dynamically-create-row-means-for-multiple-group)):

```r
zed <- data.frame(
  aAgg = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
  bAgg = c(8, 16, 24, 32),
  aPg = c(6, 9, 11, 24),
  bPg = c(7, 15, 22, 26)
)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
zed %>% 
  split.default(
    sub('^(.{1}).*', '\\1', names(zed))
  ) %>% 
  lapply(
    function(.x) .x[[1]] - .x[[2]]
  ) %>% 
  setNames(., paste0(names(.), 'Diff')) %>% 
  mutate(zed, !!!.)
#>   aAgg bAgg aPg bPg aDiff bDiff
#> 1    5    8   6   7    -1     1
#> 2   10   16   9  15     1     1
#> 3   15   24  11  22     4     2
#> 4   20   32  24  26    -4     6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>